# Express.js one function to handle GET and POST

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

Is it better to have a separate function to handle GET and POST requests for the same API endpoint or combine them into one function that discriminates based on the existence of req.body or req.params?

i.e.

```
app.get('/api/profilepic',  api.get_profilepic);
app.post('/api/profilepic',  api.change_profilepic);
```

or:

```
app.get('/api/profilepic',  api.profilepic);
app.post('/api/profilepic',  api.profilepic);
```

If the latter, does Express.js provide a helper function to determine the request type? My approach so far to determine if req is POST requires an underscore:

```
if (_.size(req.body) == 0)
```

Comment: Judging from your function names, they perform different tasks. So I would keep them separated. FWIW, you can check `req.method` to see if it contains `GET` or `POST` (or some other method, even).

Comment: There's also `app.all()` to handle both (and more)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best practice is to separate concerns; therefore, you should have separate functions to handle each HTTP verb. This makes the code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 21):

There is no general rule, the best approach depends on the case you are working on. I think if you want an api endpoint that accept POST and GET requests combined, you should use express function all() like this:

```
app.all('/api/profilepic',  api.get_profilepic);
```

You should use seperate endpoints for POST and GET when the handler function is not the same.

For more details see:
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: I tried to use "use" but it didnt work, thaks for "all"